# How to preserve scale in rasterio

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I am masking a GeoTiFF using `rasterio`. I have datasets to clip. Some images are not scaled properly when loaded to QGIS. How do you preserve the scale of the input image to the masked image using rasterio?

Is there a way to force this as an argument?

```
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask

with fiona.open("test_polygon.json", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open("example_swr.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta
    
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "dtype": rasterio.float32,
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open("swr_masked.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

[image]

**[EXAMPLE FILES](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dAENluuhM3k5yRsxNOItqGUX-Pm0s6yy?usp=share_link)**.